# Why can't I see the MyPlayer store in NBA2k14?

Tags: nba2k14

So I've tried everything - I went on my features, no MyPlayer store, I went on my career, no MyPlayer store. I'm connected to the internet, but do I need a paid PSN account to buy clothes?

Comment: As far as I know, PS+ is only needed for playing online on a PS4 as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, you need a 2K account.

Answer (score -2):

they shut down 2k14. no store soory